# Add Quotes in url string from file

Tags: python, ruby, perl

I need script to add quotes in url string from url.txt

from `http://www.site.com/info.xx` to `"http://www.site.com/info.xx"`

Comment: Question could be clearer. Do you mean to read in a text file of URLs (one to a line ?) and output the same strings wrapped in quotes ?

Answer (score 7):

```
url = '"%s"' % url
```

Example:

```
line = 'http://www.site.com/info.xx  \n'
url = '"%s"' % line.strip()
print url # "http://www.site.com/info.xx"
```

Remember, adding a backslash before a quotation mark will escape it and therefore won't end the string.

Answer (score 4):

```
url = '"%s"' % url
```

Example:

```
>>> url = "http://www.site.com/info.xx"
>>> print url
http://www.site.com/info.xx
>>> url = '"%s"' % url
>>> print url
"http://www.site.com/info.xx"
>>>
```

Parsing it from a file:

```
from __future__ import with_statement

def parseUrlsTXT(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            url = '"%s"' % line[:-1]
            print url
```

Usage:

```
parseUrlsTXT('/your/dir/path/URLs.txt')
```

Comment: `.readlines()` is redundant (`f` object is already an iterator over lines in the file). `for line in fileinput.input(): print '"%s"'%line.rstrip()` will work both for files and stdin.

Answer (score 0):

write one...
perl is my favourite scripting language... it appears you may prefer Python.

just read in the file and add \" before and after it..
this is pretty easy in perl.

this seems more like a request than a question... should this be on stackoverflow?

Comment: No question is too trivial on StackOverflow.

Comment: Personally, I think it would be easier to add the quotes on output (i.e. print "\"$url\"\n";), but however you want to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If '`url.txt`' contains a list of urls, one url per line then:

- quote the first non-whitespace character sequence:

  ```
  $ perl -pe"s~\S+~\"$&\"~" url.txt
  ```
- or trim whitespaces and quote the rest:

  ```
  $ perl -nE"$_=trim; say qq(\"$_\")" url.txt
  ```

Comment: There is no trim function in Perl, not even in 5.10.  Perhaps you mean perl -nE 's/^\s*(.*)\s*$/$1/; say qq/"$_"/' url.txt

Comment: Also, depending on the shell you are using, you may need to escape the $_ in your examples to prevent the shell variable $_ (rather than the Perl variable) from being interpolated into the program.

Answer (score 0):

A simple Perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (my $line = <>) {
    $line =~ s/\s*(.*)\s*/$1/;
    print qq/"$line"\n/;
}
```